# How to formulate the log-rank conjecture for non-boolean functions?

Tags: communication-complexity

The log-rank conjecture states that there is a constant $C$ such that  for  every two-party Boolean function $f$ it holds: $D(f) = O((\log \text{rank} (f))^C)$.

If $f$ is not a boolean function then this hypothesis is not true:
see, for example, $SUM_n(x,y)=x+y$.

What is a natural generalization of log-rank hypothesis for an arbitrary function $X \times Y \to Z$?

Comment: Constraining the alphabet size to some function of $n$ where $n$ is the size of the communication matrix makes better sense I think.